# Google Maps Marker Events

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code for google maps.  The purpose of this code is to display a map with a marker in the middle.  The marker is draggable, and when it is dropped, I need it to give the current Lat/Long where the marker was dropped.  The event doesn't always fire.  In chrome, if I just let the code run, it doesn't work.  But, if I slow it down by debugging and putting a stop on the code that attaches the event, then let it continue, it works.  It seems like there is a race condition somewhere, but I have no idea where.  Can someone please take a look and see if you come up with something.

```
function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var canvas = document.getElementById("MapCanvas");
        var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, myOptions);

        // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: initialLocation,
                    draggable: true,
                    map: map,
                    title: "You are here"
                });  
            }, function () {
                handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
            });
            // Try Google Gears Geolocation
        } else if (google.gears) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
            geo.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: initialLocation,
                    draggable: true,
                    map: map,
                    title: "You are here"
                });  
            }, function () {
                handleNoGeoLocation(browserSupportFlag);
            });
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        } else {
            browserSupportFlag = false;
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        }



        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
            $("#txtLat").val(marker.position.Ia);
            $("#txtLong").val(marker.position.Ja);
        });




    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it looks like `marker` is being initialized within one of the `getCurrentPosition` functions. I'm guessing both of these functions are asynchronous, which is why they take a callback function. However, you're trying to attach the listener function to `marker` synchronously - so under normal conditions, you're probably trying to attach the listener to `marker` before `marker` is initialized. (Also, I don't see a `var` statement for `marker`, so unless you left that out, `marker` is in the global namespace - probably not what you want).

The way to fix this is to attach the listener in the callback function, after `marker` has been initialized. Since the callback looks like it's the same for the W3C Geolocation API and the Gears API, you might want to put the whole thing into a single function:

```
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, myOptions);
    var marker;

    // set up callback
    function initMap(initialLocation) {
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        // init marker
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: initialLocation,
            draggable: true,
            map: map,
            title: "You are here"
        });
        // now attach the event
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
            // you know you'd be better off with 
            // marker.getPosition().lat(), right?
            $("#txtLat").val(marker.position.Ia);
            $("#txtLong").val(marker.position.Ja);
        });
    }

    // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred)
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            // call the callback
            initMap(new google.maps.LatLng(
                position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude
            ));
        }, function () {
            // I just assumed you weren't using 
            // browserSupportFlag anywhere else
            handleNoGeolocation(true); 
        });
    // Try Google Gears Geolocation
    } else if (google.gears) {
        var geo = google.gears.factory.create('beta.geolocation');
        geo.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            initMap(new google.maps.LatLng(
                position.latitude, position.longitude
            ));
        }, function () {
            handleNoGeoLocation(true);
        });
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    } else {
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }

}
```